# Removing Single and Multiple newlines in Python, leaving only Double newlines

Tags: python, regex, string

What I want to do is to remove all the newlines that occurs once or more than twice, leaving only
double newlines.

I want: `"\n\n"`
But not `"\n"`,`"\n\n\n"`,`"\n\n\n\n"`, and so on.

Isn't there a command to tell python "if \n occurs once or more than twice...."?

Comment: I don't really understand why this is closed. Seems perfectly suited to a the straightforward regex-based answer that @jamylak provided.

Comment: @EthanT It may have been closed because there was no code attempt shown or people thought there was no effort made in the question

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> import re
>>> text = '\n \n\n \n\n\n'
>>> re.sub(r'(?<!\n)\n(?!\n)|\n{3,}', '', text)
' \n\n '
```

Answer (score 1):

```
((?<!\n)\n{2}(?!\n))|\n+
```

Try this. Replace by `\1`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/dU7oN5/22

```
import re
re.sub(r"((?<!\n)\n{2}(?!\n))|\n+",r"\1",test_str)
```

`((?<!\n)\n{2}(?!\n))`==> Captures only `2 \n`. Lookbehind and lookahead to make sure they are exactly 2.

`\n+` ==> capture the rest

Comment: it won't work if the two newline chars are present at the last.

Comment: Why your regex captures the last two newlines where the num of \n chars at the last is 3. https://regex101.com/r/dU7oN5/21

Comment: @AvinashRaj edited.Wont now

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of completeness, here is a recursive solution without using regular expressions (`re`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

test = "this\n\nis\n\none\n\nline\nthat's not \nthis is not either\n\n\nok\n\n :)"

def count_replace(lines, count=0, target=2, char='\n'):
    print count
    if lines:
        if lines[0] == char:
            return count_replace(lines[1:], count + 1, target, char)
        if count == target:
            return lines[0] + count_replace(lines[1:], 0, target, char)
        return char * count + lines[0] + count_replace(lines[1:], 0, target, char)
    if count == target:
        return ''
    return count * char
print count_replace(test)
```